# Aquilo que dá ânsia de vômito

Tags: palavra-para-ideia, adjetivos

Um adjetivo para **aquilo que da ânsia de vômito**, como eu poderia chamar um objeto que possuísse esta característica?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Eu diria que aquilo que dá ânsia de vômito é ***nauseante***, considerando náusea como "*desejo ou ânsia de vômito; enjoo*" (terceira [definição do Google através da palavra reservada *define*](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=define:n%C3%A1usea)).

O [priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/nauseante) diz que ***nauseabundo*** é "*Nojento ou repugnante a ponto de causar náuseas*", e traz ***nauseante*** e ***nauseativo*** como sinônimos.

Veja o primeiro significado de ***nauseante*** [aqui no lexico](http://www.lexico.pt/nauseante/), que transcrevo abaixo:

> 1. Diz-se do que provoca ou causa náuseas; que faz com que se sinta vontade de vomitar;

Comment: E quer o [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/n%C3%A1usea) quer o [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/n%C3%A1usea) definem *náusea* como vontade vomitar.

Answer (score 6):

Formalmente eu chamaria de **nauseante** ou **repugnante**. Informalmente eu chamaria de **nojento**

*"Fiquei com ânsia de vômito por que achei aquilo nojento"*

*"Fiquei com ânsia de vômito por que achei aquilo repugnante"*

*"Achei aquilo nauseante, quase tive ânsia de vômito"*

Comment: Pode ser substituído "ânsia de vômito" por "vontade de vomitar"

Comment: @AndréLyra concordo!